# Incorrect Characteristic Length using iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using Swift 5.x on my iPad as a central device. The peripheral I am connected to writes 228 bytes to a read/notify characteristic (using BlueNRG-MS as the BT chip). In Swift the length of the `characteristic.value` is always 217.

If I connect with LightBlue and read the same characteristic, I see all 228 bytes there.

The max length of the `characteristic.value` is 350 bytes. On an initial connect the notification from the char is 350 zeroes. The characteristic is variable length.

At startup, when the central device connects, as a test I send the same 228 byte buffer and the central receives all 228 bytes.

I am very new to Swift, so my question is: what is preventing me from receiving the full buffer of data in the characteristic on the iOS side?

Comment: The fact that you're seeing the data in LightBlue strongly suggests that the issue is in how you're reading the data. Trimming 11 bytes is very unusual. My first assumption is that you're either not reading what you think you're reading, or the device is not sending what you think it's sending. Is the data missing from the beginning or the end of the packet? (I'm quite certain this has nothing to do with Swift in particular. This sound entirely like a confusion around BLE, or possibly Core Bluetooth.)

Comment: The one very notable issue is that 217 is an exact multiple of 31, which is a fairly common BLE packet size. It is possible that your sending stack is framing this incorrectly. But if this were the case, you would see the same thing in LightBlue. I also recommend nrfConnect as another very good BLE reader. If you really cannot reproduce this anywhere but in your Core Bluetooth code, then it suggests that's where the error is.

Comment: @RobNapier what Im seeing is this:

At startup, i write 228 bytes, no problem. Then any subsequent write to the characteristic results in the notify function in Swift being hit with the length of the char's value at 217

Comment: I changed the read/notify char to be fixed length, so first update comes in at 350 bytes total, and then all subsequent updates are limited to 217. It makes no sense

Comment: Which notify function do you mean here? `didWriteValueFor:`? `didUpdateValuesFor:`? Something else?

Comment: (And I agree it's very strange, and if this is custom firmware, I'd start with the firmware side. Maybe put a sniffer on it and check what precisely is going over the air.)

Comment: `didUpdateValueFor` is what's being used. I am concerned about some sort of MTU limitation, but then it doesn't make sense why the 228 byte write would EVER work. Its almost as if something on the BT side (stack, core bluetooth, iOS, no clue) is automatically limiting the char's value buffer to 217 bytes

Comment: And what's even MORE weird is that the data IS in the characteristic, since I can view it via Light Blue and everything is there as expected

Answer (score 0):

Searching around I think it the buffer size on the BlueNRG is only 20 bytes, maybe that has something to do with this? Maybe the controller has something in it that doesn't care about the other 122 leading zero's of the characteristic, they'd have no useful information?

BlueNRG-MS does not support an ATT_MTU greater than 20 bytes. The Characteristic can be read (not notified) in chunks, thus the mobile device is able to receive the full length when a read is triggered. [From here.](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkXaRSAV/stm32l4xx-how-to-increase-bluenrgms-attmtu)

Good luck debugging

Comment: This is for the older version of BLE. It supports up to 512 bytes for characteristics